# import decorated and wrapped function to blueprints in flask

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I have a login_required deecorated function, to manage page access.

My whole Flask project is in blueprints structured. Only main stuff is in the app.py. So I have palced the loqin_requiered function to app.py and want now to use it in my blueprint files.

app.py

```
from blueprint1 import blueprint_function1
app.register_blueprint(blueprint_function1)
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if "logged_in" in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash("Bu Sayfayi görüntülemek icin lütfen giris yapin", category="danger")
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return decorated_function
```

In my blueprint1.py I do the following:

```
from app import loqin_required
```

Then I get the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'blueprint_function1'

How can I use this decorater in other files?

Comment: you  can create a new function inside the file and intialise it with the app

Comment: can you please explain it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import login_required in blueprint1.py:

```
from app import login_required
```

Now you also import blueprint1 in app.py:

```
from blueprint1 import blueprint_function1
```

These two modules import each other, it will cause [Python Circular Dependency](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/).

To fix this, you can just create a new module to store your decorators. For example, create a `decorators.py` module aside from the app.py. Then change the import statement in blueprint1.py:

```
from decorators import login_required
```